# one ViewController for all tabs of Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a lot of common code for tabs view controllers. Is it possible to handle all tabs presses using one View Controller? The Relationship "view controllers" is used and it seems  not possible to set a name for a transition segue.

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you mean when you say "handle all tab presses"? What is it about them that you want to handle?

Comment: use one view controller for all tab bars (use segues with names)

Comment: Ok, but why do you think you would need this? What is it you are trying to achieve that makes you think you need one view controller for all tabs?

Comment: If you have a lot of common code, use a base class that the tab view controllers inherit from. That way, you can have different controllers for the different tabs, but not have to repeat a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to place [`UITabBar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) view inside of your view-controller.